# build url with GET method from 3 different forms

Tags: php, html

I have three different select forms. I would like each option and value to be appended to the URL when selected or for the URL to update values if they are changed. Here is my markup:

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <select name="apples">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<form method="GET" action="">
    <select name="oranges">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<form method="GET" action="">
    <select name="bananas">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

If apples has option 1 selected and then oranges has option 2 selected, I would like the URL to look like this:

```
www.mysite.com/?apples=1&oranges=2
```

However, using the above markup, `?apples=1` is simply replaced by `?oranges=2`, resulting in:

```
www.mysite.com/?oranges=2
```

What is the correct way to build and update the URL to reflect the option selected in each form?

Comment: Why do you need 3 forms?

Comment: The proper syntax would be `www.mysite.com/?apples=1&oranges=2` with the second `?` being a `&` instead. Also, what @ChrisWillard said.

Comment: Just use one form as a container, and replace the forms you have in your code for divs.

Comment: Or even use `fieldset` if you must

Comment: THanks - but I want just one item appended if it is selected e.g. /?apples=1 and not a long url such as ?apples=1&oranges=0&bananas=0 if the other two have nothing selected

Comment: @user1444027 Perhaps I don't understand WHY you're trying to do this.  You can use javascript to build your own URI, if you're concerned about how it looks.

Comment: @user1444027 Create one form but make the submission by javascript or jQuery to build the proper URL you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one form and one submit button. Create a default option for each select that will remain hidden, ie `<option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>`.

Try this:

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <select name="apples">
        <option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>

    <select name="oranges">
        <option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>

    <select name="bananas">
        <option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This will append only the items that have been selected. If Apples is set to 2 and the others are not selected, you'll get `www.mysite.com/?apples=2`. If Bananas is also set, you'll get `www.mysite.com/?apples=2&bananas=2`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I think you must start by using only one form, it's will help you not removing the other selected options.

Then, you must know that each select must have a selected option (by default, the first one), if you want to avoid this, you should not use a select input, more likely... a radio input.

More info : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: You can use some javascript/jquery to make your form better, look at the "on input" and "on change" event, they might help you